# Number of possible combinations in the game

Tags: problem-solving, generating-functions

The question is taken from my math book and is supposed to be solved using generating functions without any tools like a calculator, but I don't know how.

> Person A and person B is playing a game. In each round the winner gets 1 point, the loser gets 0 points and a draw gives both players a point. After an unknown number of rounds, person A has 4 points while person B has 2 points. In how many ordered combinations of rounds can this happen?

I first tried transferring the problem into an equation with three variables for person A win, person B win and draw which would have to equal 6 points in total. But failed.

Does anyone have a good solution to the problem? If there is a much easier way without generating functions, I would be happy to know that solution as well. The book says the answer is 41 combinations, but there is no explanation.

Comment: One way would be to find each of the unordered possibilities (there are not very many) and how many ways you can order each of them

Comment: Are you sure the winner doesn't collect $2$ points?  Seems odd that winning and tying are just as valuable.

Comment: Yes, only one point @lulu

Answer (score 1):

Answer is quite straight forward by enumerating cases. Observe that game must have at least 4 rounds (because in each round any player can gain almost 1 point), and cannot have more than 6 rounds (no matter the result of any round, at least one player gains 1 point in every round, for e.g. if there are 7 rounds, either A will have >4 points or B will have >2 points or both; note - points can only increase and never decrease).

**4 rounds :** Since A must gain point in every round, he can either Win or Draw. Since B cannot have >2 points, he must win 0 points in exactly 2 out of 4 rounds. The only way this can happen is :
A wins 2 rounds, draws 2 rounds. Possibilities : 6

**5 rounds :** By similar analysis, you can prove that the only way to do this is when A wins exactly 3 rounds, draws 1 round & loses 1 round. Possibilities: 20

**6 rounds :**  A must win exactly 4 rounds and lose exactly 2. Possibilities :  15

Total : 6+20+15 = **41**

Answer (score 0):

If there are $d$ draws, then player A gets $4-d$ wins and player B gets $2-d$ wins, and the number of ordered combinations is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{6-d}{d,4-d,2-d}$, so the total is
$$\sum_{d=0}^2 \binom{6-d}{d,4-d,2-d} = \binom{6}{0,4,2} + \binom{5}{1,3,1} + \binom{4}{2,2,0} = 15 + 20 + 6 = 41$$